# Show different component conditionally if parent tag contains active class - Vue Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to customize tab component's title part on Vue Bootstrap. If the tab is active, I want to show different type of tab item. Of course we can solve it by using css classes by setting .active class. But In my situation, I want to display a different component if that tab is active.

I believe this can be done using 'v-if' but I dont know how to get its tag's classes contains active class. If tab is active, I want to render a spinner component, else I only want to render name of that tab.

Do you have any idea?

```
<b-tabs fill>  
        <b-tab title="First">
            <template #title v-if="active">
                <b-spinner type="grow" small variant="success"></b-spinner> <b>Active Title</b>
            </template>
            <template #title v-else> 
                <b>Title</b>
            </template>
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Second">
            <template #title v-if="active"> 
                <b-spinner type="grow" small variant="success"></b-spinner> <b>Second Title</b>
            </template>
            <template #title v-else> 
                <b>Title</b>
            </template>
        </b-tab>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind a property to `<b-tabs>` v-model, which will contain the index of the active tab. Then use this to check inside your `v-if` whether the tab is active or not.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      currentTab: 0
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <b-tabs v-model="currentTab" fill>
    <b-tab title="First">
      <template #title v-if="currentTab === 0">
        <b-spinner type="grow" small variant="success"></b-spinner> <b>Active Title</b>
      </template> Tab 1 content
    </b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Second">
      <template #title v-if="currentTab === 1"> 
        <b-spinner type="grow" small variant="success"></b-spinner> <b>Second Title</b>
      </template> Tab 2 content
    </b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
</div>
```